# can not access the php file in the sub folders?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, apache2

after re-install the apache ant php , I meet a problem, only the php file in the root folder can access, the php file in the sub folder of root can not access.

I am using apache2.2 php4.3 and codeigniter php framework.

```
    #apache config
    <Location /gl>
    </Location>
    Alias /gl /mnt/deploy/hospital


when I put file in "http://.../gl/application/controllers/test1.php", the browser report 500 error, and I check the /var/log/apache2/error.log no php error find.

when I put file in "http://.../gl/test1.php" thing's ok.
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it cannot be accessed'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell apache who is allowed to access the alias.

Try

```
Alias /gl /mnt/deploy/hospital
<Directory "/mnt/deploy/hospital">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1

</Directory>
```

If you must, and you are not working on a local testing environment use :-

```
Allow from all
```

instead of

```
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1
```