# Can't reach subdirectory urls

Tags: php, plesk

I have a site with Plesk panel. After updating the php version I can't reach files that are not in the root directory. For example:
`www.example.com/rootfile.php` is reachable but `www.example.com/subdir/subdirfile.php` is not. Redirecting me to the home page. Where can I fix these in Plesk ? Thank you!

```
# Start iDevAffiliate SEO Code

RewriteEngine On

# Forced Tier Linking Code
RewriteRule ^signup-([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/signup\.php?ref=$1 [R=301,L]

# TextAds
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/idevads\.php?id=$1&ad=$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/idevads\.php?id=$1&ad=$3&page=$4 [R=301,L]

# Custom Links
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)-url\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/idevaffiliate\.php?id=$1&keyword=$2&url=$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)-custom\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/idevaffiliate\.php?id=$1&keyword=$2&custom=$3 [R=301,L]

# Standard Links
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/idevaffiliate\.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/idevaffiliate\.php?id=$1&page=$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/idevaffiliate\.php?id=$1&page=$2&set=$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/idevaffiliate\.php?id=$1&page=$2&set=$3&link=$4 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/idevaffiliate\.php?id=$1&page=$2&set=$3&link=$4&keyword=$5 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/idevaffiliate\.php?id=$1&page=$2&set=$3&link=$4&keyword=$5&custom=$6 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www\.cvtrumpet\.co\.uk/idevaffiliate/idevaffiliate\.php?id=$1&page=$2&set=$3&link=$4&keyword=$5&custom=$6&url=$7 [R=301,L]

# End iDevAffiliate SEO Code

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    <Files ~ (\.htm$)>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .htm
        Options +ExecCGI
    </Files>
    <Files ~ (\.html$)>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .htm
        Options +ExecCGI
    </Files>
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12 .docm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document docx
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template dotx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12 potm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template potx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12 ppam
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12 ppsm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow ppsx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12 pptm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation pptx
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12 xlam
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12 xlsb
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12 xlsm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12 xltm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template xltx

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} candidatelogin.htm
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.cvtrumpet.co.uk/candidatelogin.htm [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} recruiterlogin.htm
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.cvtrumpet.co.uk/recruiterlogin.htm [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} candidatelogin.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.cvtrumpet.co.uk/candidatelogin.php [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} recruiterlogin.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.cvtrumpet.co.uk/recruiterlogin.php [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} recruiters-jobs-search.htm
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.cvtrumpet.co.uk/recruiters-jobs-search.htm [R,L]


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} signup1of3.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.cvtrumpet.co.uk/signup1of3.php [R,L]
```

Comment: are your website hosted on apache? if yes, check the .htaccess and the files/subdirectories permissions

Comment: Yes, its apache. Htacces is not changed after the php version update. Permission are 644 for all the files and 755 for directories.

Comment: can you please post the htaccess?

Comment: Done. Pasted all of it.

Comment: are you sure that none of those Rewrite is redirecting/blocking the access? try to remove this file (or save it with a different name) and see if this behavior persist

Comment: Tried, this is not the case.

Comment: what's the current version and which was the previus?

Comment: Current is 7.1 and prev was 5.3.

Comment: please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107877/can-not-access-the-php-file-in-the-sub-folders